# how to call a deployed ssis 2012 package from execute package task from another ssis package

Tags: ssis

I have a ssis 2012 package that has been deployed on the server. Now I am creating another ssis package that will call that deployed package through execute package task. Can someone tell me how to achieve this. ?

I tried to do the following things -

1. tried to find the deployed path so that I can use that path inside execute package task. But I could not find the path in which package is deployed. can my goal be achieved in this way.
2. Tried to use execute sql task instead of execute package task but this did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Select `Project Reference` for child packages that are in the project. Select `External Reference` for child packages that are located outside the package.

[image]

Set to `External Reference` if the project that contains the package has not been converted to the project deployment model.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh479606.aspx

If you are trying access package already deployed in `SSISDB Catalog` through `Execute Package Task`, then you have to download that project and include your parent package to that project. As end of the day you will be required to deploy your parent package to the same SSISDB catalog (You can not access package of different project through `Execute Package task`).

**To Execute package through Execute SQL Task:**
you can script out the TSQL code of your SSISDB deployed package by `Right cLick on package>Execute>Script to...`

```
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] 
        @folder_name = N'Folder',
        @project_name = N'Test',
        @package_name = N'Package.dtsx',
        @reference_id = NULL,
        @use32bitruntime = FALSE,     
        @execution_id = @executionID OUTPUT

    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
    @executionID,
    @object_type = 20, 
    @parameter_name = N'Var1', 
    @parameter_value = @Var1

    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
    @executionID,
    @object_type = 20, 
    @parameter_name = N'Var2', 
    @parameter_value = @Var2

    EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @executionID
```